# Elasticsearch How to put selected rows items on top of results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How can I put selected items on top of results?  For example I want id 3 and 4 on top after sort by name.  Similar to SQL Order in query.

Let's say I have an index call person.
GET person/_search

```
{
hits: [
  "_source" : {
     "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Paul"
  },
  "_source" : {
     "id" : 2,
      "name" : “Mike”
  },
  "_source" : {
     "id" : 3,
      "name" : “Alex”
  },
  "_source" : {
     "id" : 4,
      "name" : “Susan”
  }
```

]
}

My current search query:

```
{  "track_total_hits": true,
"from" : 0,
"size" : 30,
"query":{
  "query_string":
  {
    "query": " some query matchin"
  }
},    "sort" :
[
  {"nae" : {"order" : "desc"}}
]    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom script to sort the documents. There will be two sort.

1. custom script : to sort on selected values
2. sort on name  : sort based on names

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": "if(params.names.containsKey(doc['name.keyword'].value)) { return params.names[doc['name.keyword'].value];} return 100;",
                "params": {
                    "names": {
                        "Susan": 0,
                        "Alex": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    {
      "name.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need simply to display the results sorted by name, try this:

Kibana > Discover > index person > add name from Available fields and do then a sort by name